how to add an image on the selected field in a dbgrid in Delphi 7
I want to add an image to the selected field in a dbgrid in Delphi 7. The dbgrid displays many fields. If the user selects a field, I have to add an image to its title.
Thanks,
Sridhar
enter image description here
I was able to do the below
  for iCtr := 0 to pred(dbgDomain.columns.count) do
  begin
    if dbgDomain.columns[iCtr].fieldname = column.fieldname then
    begin
      dbgDomain.columns[iCtr].title.font.color := clBlue;
      dbgDomain.columns[iCtr].title.font.style :=
        dbgDomain.columns[iCtr].title.font.style + [fsBold];
    end
    else
    begin
      dbgDomain.columns[iCtr].title.font.color := clWindowText;
      dbgDomain.columns[iCtr].title.font.style :=
        dbgDomain.columns[iCtr].title.font.style - [fsBold];
    end;
  end;

